# Ember many instances of the same view and pushObject method

Tags: ember.js, push, handlebars.js

I want to use many instances of the same `view`  to display same kind of data from different sources (just logger checking some distance app instances), I created simple view which contains empty `logs` array and method for fetching data with AJAX (dummy `for` loop in the sample code). unfortunately `logs` property is shared between the instances, so every view displays items of all other instances, why is that? Why aren't they encapsulated to current instance ?

There is a JsFiddle showing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/biesior/wYGLT/

And there's it's code:

HTML:

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    ellou' Logger
    {{#view App.SomeLogger id="logger1"}}{{/view}} <br>
    {{#view App.SomeLogger id="logger2"}}{{/view}} <br>
    {{#view App.SomeLogger id="logger3"}}{{/view}} <br>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="logger-template">
    <h1>ID: {{view.elementId}}</h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each log in view.logs}}
        <li>{{log.txt}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    <ul>
</script>

<script>
App = Ember.Application.create({ rootElement: "#main"});
App.SomeLogger = Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName: 'logger-template',
    logs: [],
    init: function () {
        this._super();
        var inst = this;
        setTimeout(function(){ inst.readLogs() }, 500);
    }, 
    readLogs: function(){
        var inst = this;
        var logs = inst.get("logs");
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            logs.pushObject({txt: 'Log no.: ' + i + " in: " + inst.get("elementId")});
        }
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because you are declaring an shared array instance in the `SomeLogger` class. You need to create it inside of `init`, so each new `SomeLogger` created will have your own `logs` array.

```
App.SomeLogger = Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName: 'logger-template',
    logs: null,
    init: function () {
        this._super();
        this.set('logs', []); // each new SomeLogger created will have your own array
        var inst = this;
        setTimeout(function(){ inst.readLogs() }, 500);
    }, 
    readLogs: function(){
        var inst = this;
        var logs = inst.get("logs");
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            logs.pushObject({txt: 'Log no.: ' + i + " in: " + inst.get("elementId")});
        }
    }

});
```

This is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/RrKzh/